# Android : Ksoap2 request error missing element

Tags: android, wsdl, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

i am using KSOAP2 to consume SAP web service

this is the success request and response

REQUEST

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" 
xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<urn:SdRfcCustomerGet xmlns:urn="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
<CustomerT>
<item>
<Kunnr></Kunnr>
<Anred></Anred>
<Name1></Name1>
<Pfach></Pfach>
<Stras></Stras>
<Pstlz></Pstlz>
<Telf1></Telf1>
<Telfx></Telfx>
<Ort01></Ort01>
</item>
</CustomerT>
<Kunnr>0000491100</Kunnr>
<Name1></Name1>
</urn:SdRfcCustomerGet>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

RESPONSE

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap-env:Header/>
   <soap-env:Body>
      <n0:SdRfcCustomerGetResponse xmlns:n0="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
         <CustomerT>
            <item>
               <Kunnr>0000491100</Kunnr>
               <Anred/>
               <Name1>Customer Company 02</Name1>
               <Pfach>127 353</Pfach>
               <Stras>Sheikh Zayed Road</Stras>
               <Pstlz/>
               <Ort01>Berlin</Ort01>
               <Telf1/>
               <Telfx/>
            </item>
         </CustomerT>
      </n0:SdRfcCustomerGetResponse>
   </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

This is the request and response generated by my Android code

REQUEST

```
<v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<v:Header />
<v:Body>
<SdRfcCustomerGet xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
<CustomerT>
<item>
<Kunnr></Kunnr>
<Anred></Anred>
<Name1></Name1>
<Pfach></Pfach>
<Stras></Stras>
<Pstlz></Pstlz>
<Telf1></Telf1>
<Telfx></Telfx>
<Ort01></Ort01>
</item>
</CustomerT>
<Kunnr>0000491100</Kunnr>
<Name1></Name1>
</SdRfcCustomerGet>
</v:Body>
</v:Envelope>
```

RESPONSE

```
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap-env:Header/>
<soap-env:Body>
<soap-env:Fault>
<faultcode>soap-env:Server</faultcode>
<faultstring xml:lang="en">Processing Error. More details in WS Error Log (transaction SRT_UTIL) by selection with UTC timestamp 20131202115430 </faultstring>
<detail/>
</soap-env:Fault>
</soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

the error generated in eclipse

```
SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap-env:Server' faultstring: 'Processing Error. More details in WS Error Log (transaction SRT_UTIL) by selection with UTC timestamp 20131202115430 ' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@41c9e4a0
```

error on  server

----`ERROR_TEXT Element 'CustomerT' missing`

the line i need to change in request is this

```
<SdRfcCustomerGet xmlns="urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style">
```

i need to change it to ( i want to add ns1 or urn or n0 before function name )

```
<ns1:SdRfcCustomerGet xmlns:ns1='urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style'>
```

can anyone help me with this

i have been stuck for a week now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it that way

```
SoapObject request = new SoapObject("", "urn:" + WS_METHOD_NAME);
request.addAttribute("xmlns:urn", WS_NAMESPACE);
```